# How to change thickness / height of lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, responsive-design

I found this codepen that I'd like to use but want the lines to appear 'thinner'.  Which variable do I change?

Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/tholman/pen/Jochj?q=homepage&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false) to the code and here is the code:

```
<canvas id="stripes">
  (function() {
var lastTime = 0;
var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = 
 window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] 
                               || 
 window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
 }

if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
    window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
        var currTime = new Date().getTime();
        var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
        var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); }, 
          timeToCall);
        lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
        return id;
    };

if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
        clearTimeout(id);
    };
 }());

 var Nodes = {

 // Settings
density: 6,
reactionSensitivity: 3,

points: [],
lines: [[], []],
mouse: { x: -1000, y: -1000, down: false },

animation: null,

canvas: null,
context: null,

init: function() {
// Set up the visual canvas 
this.canvas = document.getElementById( 'stripes' );
this.context = this.canvas.getContext( '2d' );
this.context.lineJoin = 'bevel';
this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
this.canvas.style.display = 'block'

this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove, false);
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown, false);
this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   this.mouseUp,   false);
this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseout',  this.mouseOut,  false);

window.onresize = function(event) {
  Nodes.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  Nodes.canvas.height = Math.max(window.innerHeight, 670);
  Nodes.onWindowResize();    
}

this.preparePoints();
this.draw();

},

preparePoints: function() {

// Clear the current points
this.points = [];
this.lines = [[],[]];

var width, height, i;
var center = window.innerHeight / 2;

for( i = -10; i < this.canvas.width + 10; i += this.density ) {

  var line1 = {y: center - 17, originalY: center - 10, color: '#B1FB17'};
  var line2 = {y: center - 17, originalY: center - 25, color: '#F52887'};

  line1["x"] =  i;
  line1["originalX"] = i;

  line2["x"] =  i;
  line2["originalX"] = i;

  this.points.push(line1);
  this.points.push(line2);

  this.lines[0].push(line1);
  this.lines[1].push(line2);
 }
 },

updatePoints: function() {

var i, currentPoint, theta, distance;

for (i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++ ){

  currentPoint = this.points[i];

  theta = Math.atan2( currentPoint.y - this.mouse.y, currentPoint.x - this.mouse.x);

  if ( this.mouse.down ) {
    distance = this.reactionSensitivity * 300 / Math.sqrt((this.mouse.x - currentPoint.x) * (this.mouse.x - currentPoint.x) +
     (this.mouse.y - currentPoint.y) * (this.mouse.y - currentPoint.y));
  } else {
    distance = this.reactionSensitivity * 150 / Math.sqrt((this.mouse.x - currentPoint.x) * (this.mouse.x - currentPoint.x) +
     (this.mouse.y - currentPoint.y) * (this.mouse.y - currentPoint.y));  
  }

  currentPoint.x += Math.cos(theta) * distance + (currentPoint.originalX - currentPoint.x) * 0.07;
  currentPoint.y += Math.sin(theta) * distance + (currentPoint.originalY - currentPoint.y) * 0.07;

 }
 },

 drawPoints: function() {

 var i, currentPoint;

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var line = this.lines[i];
  this.context.beginPath();
  this.context.lineJoin = 'round';
  this.context.moveTo( line[0].x, line[0].y);
  this.context.strokeStyle = line[0].color;
  this.context.lineWidth = 10;
  for (var j = 1; j < line.length - 2; j++) {
    var point = line[j];

    var xc = (point.x + line[j + 1].x) / 2;
    var yc = (point.y + line[j + 1].y) / 2;

    this.context.quadraticCurveTo(point.x, point.y, xc, yc);

   }
  this.context.stroke();
  this.context.closePath();
   }
  },

 draw: function() {
  this.animation = requestAnimationFrame( function(){ Nodes.draw() } );

  this.clear();
  this.updatePoints();
  this.drawPoints();

},

clear: function() {
  this.canvas.width = this.canvas.width;
},

mouseDown: function( event ){
Nodes.mouse.down = true;
},

mouseUp: function( event ){
  Nodes.mouse.down = false;
 },

mouseMove: function(event){
  Nodes.mouse.x = event.pageX;
  Nodes.mouse.y = event.pageY;
 },

 mouseOut: function(event){
  Nodes.mouse.x = -1000;
  Nodes.mouse.y = -1000;
  Nodes.mouse.down = false;
  },

// Resize and redraw the canvas.
onWindowResize: function() {
cancelAnimationFrame( this.animation );
this.preparePoints();
this.draw();
}

}

// Start the app. 
setTimeout( function() {
  Nodes.init();
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for linewidth - actually with a bit of reading you cold solve this yourself!